# starting index of a unique string in a each and every file in shell scripting

Tags: string, shell, indexing, scripting

I have below requirement where in a directory I have a list of files and i have to find a unique string's starting index in each and every file.This string is common to each and every file. It would be better if i get a solution for this in shell scripting.

[image]

is list of files and suppose i want to find starting index of string ",hi,this,is,vijay,kumar" which will come for sure in each and every file.

Comment: I understand you want to find the common prefix among a list of files in a directory, that's clear. But I do not understand is the "suppose i want to find starting index of string ",hi,this,is,vijay,kumar" which will come for sure in each and everyfile." part, can you explain better?

Comment: for example i have given the string ",hi,this,is,vijay,kumar" which will come for sure in the content of each and every file and only once and i want to know the starting index of the string mentioned in each and every file.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider these test files:

```
$ cat file1
,hi,this,is,vijay,kumar
$ cat file2
Some text here,hi,this,is,vijay,kumar
$ cat file3
Some more text
here that goes
on,hi,this,is,vijay,kumar
```

To find the location, in bytes, of your string in each file:

```
$ grep -ob ',hi,this,is,vijay,kumar' file*
file1:0:,hi,this,is,vijay,kumar
file2:14:,hi,this,is,vijay,kumar
file3:32:,hi,this,is,vijay,kumar
```

`-b` tells grep to return the 0-based byte offset within the input file.  `-o` tells grep to return the byte offset of the matched string itself, not the line that the matched string is on.

From the results, we see that your string occurs at byte offset 0 of file1, byte offset 14 of file2, and byte offset 32 of file3.

Replace `file*` with the names of your files or, even easier, any glob that matches the names of the files of interest to you.  From your image, that might be `201606231142_63*`.

Comment: hi John,   

this is how i it was showing in putty when i run the command suggested by you.

201606231442_6372.214:0:,CLT,*********************,ES,
201606231442_6373.214:0:,CLT,*********************,ES,

i want to highlight "0" after file name

Comment: Try: `grep -ob ',hi,this,is,vijay,kumar' file* | sed "s/:[0-9]*:/$(tput smso)&$(tput rmso)/"`